# Parsing Array within Array: Unwanted cartesian-product behavior

Tags: jq

Using `jq`, I am trying to parse an array of values, each with a nested array.

My attempt has created a cartesian product of all possible values instead of parsing specific properties within the nested array.

```bash
jq '.[] | {id, versions: (.versions[] | {id}) }'
```

**Source**

```json
[{
  "id": "afe45456-18fd-4523-a0ee-b7ed9d0a308e",
  ***,
  "versions": [{
    "id": "07e34a2d-be28-4925-afdd-79ddcbe54db9",
    ***
  },
  {
    "id": "0e4ea89c-49da-4f79-a6bc-eec0dad19133",
    ***
  }],
  ***
},
{
  "id": "3644e592-c9c3-4c3b-b6d4-e6a7dbdf80fb",
  ***,
  "versions": [{
    "id": "9d63e112-7c42-43fa-b460-3f4389b691b3",
    ***
  }],
  ***
}]
```

**Expecting**

```json
[{
  "id": "afe45456-18fd-4523-a0ee-b7ed9d0a308e",
  "versions": [{
    "id": "07e34a2d-be28-4925-afdd-79ddcbe54db9"
  },
  {
    "id": "0e4ea89c-49da-4f79-a6bc-eec0dad19133"
  }]
},
{
  "id": "3644e592-c9c3-4c3b-b6d4-e6a7dbdf80fb",
  "versions": [
  {
    "id": "9d63e112-7c42-43fa-b460-3f4389b691b3"
  }]
}]
```

**Actual: cartesian-product behavior**

```json
{
  "id": "afe45456-18fd-4523-a0ee-b7ed9d0a308e",
  "versions": {
    "id": "07e34a2d-be28-4925-afdd-79ddcbe54db9"
  }
}
{
  "id": "afe45456-18fd-4523-a0ee-b7ed9d0a308e",
  "versions": {
    "id": "0e4ea89c-49da-4f79-a6bc-eec0dad19133"
  }
}
{
  "id": "3644e592-c9c3-4c3b-b6d4-e6a7dbdf80fb",
  "versions": {
    "id": "9d63e112-7c42-43fa-b460-3f4389b691b3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get arrays, not a stream of items (in both, the inner and the outer case), don't destructure the source array with `.[]`, use `map` instead which retains the surrounding array:

```bash
jq 'map({id, versions: (.versions | map({id})) })'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/8nXO8WgNpXj)